# About the equations of planes

Tags: vectors

In vectors if they ask to find equation of plane passing through a point and perpendicular to a vector then we need to find cartesian equation or vector equation

Comment: Where's the question? Please clarify and [add your own thoughts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: see here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfPlanes.aspx

Comment: So you're wondering about the **form** of the equation that you should write? I guess it doesn't really matter, as long as you define the correct plane. Or it might depend on the course, what the teacher requires etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find plane by normal and instance point + distance between origin and plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752252/find-plane-by-normal-and-instance-point-distance-between-origin-and-plane)